# IIS Express not working on vs code "Unable to start iisexpress"

Tags: vscode-extensions, iis-express-10

[image: Error message received]

IIS Express Extension not starting and can't launch Asp Net app.

I enabled IIS in 'Turn Windows features on or off'

Installed IIS 10 Express

Installed VS Code IIS Express Extension

Tried reinstalling IIS Express and the extension. Still getting the same error.

Comment: The one you installed as Windows features is the full IIS, not IIS Express. You still have a long way to go and learn each of the tools. Talk to its developer(s) https://github.com/warrenbuckley/IIS-Express-Code/issues and learn how to configure it properly.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: My company ships a new extension to enable IIS/IIS Express management for VS Code, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lextudio.iis You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Program.cs file within your Asp Net app? That is typically where .NET looks to find everything to start running.

Answer (score 0):

> I enabled IIS in 'Turn Windows features on or off'

Here you installed IIS, not IIS express. IIS Express is equivalent to a stripped-down version of IIS, which has almost all the functions of IIS, but it has no visual management interface, and all management operations are performed by modifying configuration files.

Download IIS Express from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264) and install on the developer PC.

After installation, the IIS Express configuration files will be available in **"Documents\IISExpress\config"** and the IIS Express executable files will be available in the installation directory. For example: C:\Program Files\IIS Express; Set the environment variable path to "C:\Program Files\IIS Express". (Open advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> System Variables -> Path -> Edit ->New -> add the path C:\Program Files\IIS Express). About Using IIS Express, please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line).

> The specified module could not be found.
> For more information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled (/trace:error).

Check if there is an IISExpress\config folder in your home folder. This is a common mistake when configuration files/folders are missing. If the directory does not exist, you will need to create the directory; or the directory may already exist and is just corrupted, you will need to delete the config directory and re-run `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe/trace:error`